# How to list all build-in / pre-defined Monolog channels in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am new to Symfony 5.3 and Monolog. The [docu](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html) explains *"the Symfony Framework organizes log messages into channels. By default, there are several channels, including doctrine, event, security, request and more."*

**Is there any way to find out what channels exactly are configured?**

I tried to run `php bin/console debug:config monolog` but this only shows the channels I configured (e.g. by adding `channels: ['myChannelA', 'channelB']` to the `monolog.yaml`)

I made no changes (beside adding custom channels, see above) to the default monolog config which was created on install:

```
// config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    channels: ['myChannelA','channelB']
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type: firephp
        #    level: info
        #chromephp:
        #    type: chromephp
        #    level: info
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]

// config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
            buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: php://stderr
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.json
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
```

Comment: I edited the question and added the `monolog.yaml` files. No changes were made beside adding two custom channels to check if they are listed when using `php bin/console debug:config monolog`. Other channels are not listed and not included in the config files.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following command:

> php bin/console debug:autowiring | grep monolog